# matplotlib grouped bar chart and line graph is not align to x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot a line graph with grouped bar chart together.
So when I combine it, the line graph will start from 4 but not 2.

Below is the combined line graph and grouped bar chart:

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPwE6.png)

and this is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('instagram_category.csv')

sales = df_total.groupby(['Month']).sum()['Daily Sales']
df = df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Type', values='Count')
df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 8))
sales.plot(secondary_y=True)

plt.title('Daily Sales X Instagram Categories')
plt.show()
```

but when I separate the line graph and grouped bar chart, the line graph can show correctly, any idea how should I fix it?

*This is my code for single line graph

```
sales = df_total.groupby(['Month']).sum()['Daily Sales']
keys_1 = [month for month, df in df_total.groupby(['Month'])]
plt.plot(keys_1, sales,color='#b15a5e',linewidth = 3)
plt.xlabel('month')
plt.ylabel('sales')
plt.show()
```

and [line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TORkp.png)

Comment: Pandas' bar chart are plotted against range index `0,1,..., len(df)-1` and labeled by the index/x-column.

Comment: Sorry I am quiet new to Pandas, can you explain the detail for me? So is it possible to combine the line and bar chart together?